# How to download an image from Twilio whatsapp API with Node.js

Tags: node.js, twilio, media, whatsapp

My goal is to get the image from Twilio api to store it somewhere else because Twilio deletes media after 4h.
[(See here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2AdV.png)

I'm using node and I have read https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/media-resource#fetch-a-media-resource

...and it says that to do a request to this URL without the "json" extension should return the media with its original MIME type

[https://api.twilio.com/2010-041/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages/{MessageSid}/Media/{Sid}.json](https://api.twilio.com/2010-041/Accounts/%7BAccountSid%7D/Messages/%7BMessageSid%7D/Media/%7BSid%7D.json)

However, i need auth, so I need to use

`const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);`

How can I fetch the image? Any sample code to achieve it? In the docs seem to do it without auth.

UPDATE ----------------------------------------

After accessing the `MediaUrl0` on the browser, twilio redirects me to the following URL:

[https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/media.twiliocdn.com/{AccountSid}/{?}](https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/media.twiliocdn.com/%7BAccountSid%7D/%7B?%7D)

I was thinking of building my own URL but i dont know how to get the `{?}`

Comment: Hi you resolve the problem? I have the same problem trying to upload the media to my S3, cant find the way to get {?}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need authentication to retrieve media for an incoming sms . They are all hosted (as of now on Aws S3) and accessible publicly through a (hard to guess) url.
you can access them using any http client